# Is this logic correct to determine whether this extension is safe to use with my induction cooktop?

Tags: voltage, power, current

I'm having a hard time understand ampere, power and voltage. I'm not a science student, but want to understand this basic thing.

The max power (I don't know if **power** is correct to say or not, but max 1200 W is written on it. So I guess this power) of my induction cooktop is 1200 W.

I have a Philips extension which have following written on its back:

6A 250V~ 1500W (Max).

So I assume this means: P = VI So 1500 W = 250V x 6A

It makes sense.

Now, Indian electricity *comes* at 220 V.

So in that case, my induction cooktop will have the following power relation, when I'm using it at its max power (i.e., 1200 W):

1200 W =  220 V x I
I = 1200/220
I = 5.4 approx.

So let's say 5.4 A (ampere) *(AM I CORRECT TO CONCLUDE THIS?)*

Now, what I've written above is correct, I will assume this basic concept and meanings of voltage, ampere and power are somewhat clear to me.

**Now, main question: According to extension specifications, I can use it for a load (is it called load?) of 1500 W. But my load (induction cooktop) is 300 W less, so technically there won't be any problem?**

I've seen my friends who use extensions for coolers and they burst/damaged. I don't want that experience.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input power may be up to 10% higher than the output power load selected due to efficiency loss.

The heater will not have the surge current>500% at the startup of the ACU. Thus there should be no concerns with your grounded extension cord. It might feel slightly warm at best on max power.

Comment: Can you please clarify one more thing. I've somewhere that this laptop charger has this much voltage or it is of N number of volts. What does it mean? I thought voltage is of electricity?

Comment: Power = Volts x Amps

Comment: I know this. But does it mean they are actually talking about the power of the charger and just said it indirectly? Like I can say my induction cooktop is of 220V?

Comment: The label will have the AC power or current and voltage for max load as well on the DC side.

Comment: Tony little difficult for me to understand this.

Comment: The laptop will be 65W max or similar thus 240V@ 0.25A and 19V @ 3.2A or so for similar power out